# fortran FORMAT scale factor (k) number fractional digits (d) allowed combination

Tags: fortran

```
    READ (unit=10,FMT=900) X
    READ (unit=11,FMT=900) Y
900 FORMAT (D20.0)
```

when i compile my program with `ifort -O2` the remark is

line 503 --> remark #8577: The scale factor (k) and number of fractional digits (d) do not have the allowed combination of either -d < k <= 0 or 0 < k < d+2. Expect asterisks as output.

line number 503 is the `900 FORMAT (D20.0)` in the code snippet above, and the only 2 lines in the program were those read statements.
can someone explain what is going on?
never had this "remark" using older versions of intel compiler.
i am currently using the version 16.0 compiler.
thanks.

Comment: See [this Intel forum post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/384614), perhaps.

Comment: in your link Intel says to change E11.0 to F11.0.  I am not sure what my format of `D` is, double precision i guess?   I changed my format from `D20.0` to `D20.1` and the remark statement does not happen, and as far as i can tell my output is the same.  so i am going to stick with `D20.1` and call it good.  thanks.

Comment: `D` is essentially the same as `E` but is with `double precision` in mind.  In particular, on output it allows numbers like `4.2d+03` but not `4.2e+003` or `4.2d+003`.  For input, though, they are interchangeable.

Comment: All else aside, it is quite likely you don't need that format at all.  What does the input look like?

Comment: just to try to explain the specific error, since you have not specified a scal factor, `k` is `0`. So you need `-d<0` thus `d>=1`. ie `d20.1` will not throw the error. (Unlikely to be what you actually want for a formatted read though.  Note the second inequalty is actually inconsistent, not evidently permitting the default value for `k`.  (its probably really `d+2>0 && d+2>k` )

Comment: the data being read is like this  `6.9596223196072D-001  9.0529467285308D-003`  and actually some of the `READ` statements that were using the `FORMAT D20.0` were this:  `READ (UNIT=C1, FMT=900) X` and `READ (UNIT=C2, FMT=900) Y`  where `C1` and `C2` each are of type `CHARACTER*20`

Comment: @agentp, it may be that you are mis-reading the requirement.  If k is zero then it is required that d be (strictly) greater than 0.  That is, 0<k<d+2 isn't meant as those two other conditions.  [After all, d+2>0 is a little unnecessary if we know that d is itself required to be positive.]

Comment: the data being read from a text file is like this  `6.9596223196072D-001  9.0529467285308D-003`  and actually some of the `READ` statements that were using the `FORMAT D20.0` were this:  `READ (UNIT=C1, FMT=900) X` and `READ (UNIT=C2, FMT=900) Y`  where `C1` and `C2` each are of type `CHARACTER*20` and `C1` has the contents of  `6.9596223196072D-001` and `C2` has the contents of `9.0529467285308D-003`

Comment: If you are going to change the format to remove the remark, a better choice may be `F20.0`.  Using `F` edit descriptors or `D` or `E` processes the input field in the same way and there is no restriction on the `.0` fractional part for ifort to get confused about.

Comment: @francescalus right I missed the "OR" when I read that.  Interestingly my (ifort) version of the message has `-d<k<0` for the first condition which *is* inconsistent as neither condition permits `k=0` (the default)

Comment: @agentp, prompted by your pointing out that inequality I think I finally understand what the Intel people were saying, thanks.

Comment: Mine is ifort 13.1.  Ron you can just use `read(unit,*)` for those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please note that the message the compiler prints is a remark. Not even a warning, just a remark.

Secondly, the remark is only relevant when the `FORMAT` is used for output. You use it for input so the remark is not relevant in that case. The remark probably happens, because the compiler does not check where the format is referenced.

Instead of the `FORMAT` statement you can use a format string directly in the `READ` statement or as a character string variable. There is nothing really wrong with a `FORMAT` statement, it is just somewhat old-fashioned. However, the compiler will have nothing to remark about than.

```
READ (unit=10,FMT='(D20.0)') X
READ (unit=11,FMT='(D20.0)') Y
```

or

```
character(10) :: str
str = '(D20.0)'
READ (unit=10,FMT=str) X
READ (unit=11,FMT=str) Y
```

Using something like `D20.1` on input is really dangerous. I highly suggest to always use `.0` on input. The problem is that when integer values without any decimal point are read from the input file with `Dw.d` where `d` is some positive integer, they would be divided by the value 10^d but no division happens to values that already include a decimal point. This is something one typically does not want except for some very specific cases.